# iOS: Is there any notification that Siri has appeared?

Tags: iphone, notifications, siri

I would like to receive a notification each time Siri appears or disappears from the screen.
It may appear when the user puts the iPhone near his ear.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran a test and the following notifications are sent when Siri appears:

```
_UIApplicationWillAddDeactivationReasonNotification
UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
```

... and when Siri is dismissed:

```
_UIApplicationDidRemoveDeactivationReasonNotification
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
```

So, no... since there isn't a public Siri API, and UIApplication doesn't send any Siri specific notifications, it looks like we're out of luck for now.

Answer (score 2):

The only notification you'd get is a applicationDidEnterBackground (or something like that).

I don't think there are any Siri APIs at the moment so you would be looking at the OS as a whole.

Comment: This might have been true before, but applicationDidEnterBackground is not called when Siri appears anymore.