# Notification when returning to app from Siri

Tags: ios, siri

I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer in my iOS 7 app. I have it working properly where it reads text to the user, but when a user triggers Siri, speech stops and the following method is called:

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance
```

This is understandable, since you don't want to be talking over Siri. However, I don't know how to tell when the user is done with Siri and goes back into my app. None of the viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear methods seem to fire. Does anyone know what event or method to listen for?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13620475/2115477

Comment: (Sigh) I was afraid of that... those events also fire when a user pulls up control/notification center. I don't want to pause on those items...